# useState still has old value when going to previous page

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

Every page goes through an `AuthGuard` component which determines if child components can be shown or if the user needs to be redirected to another page.

It works well when first visiting a page, but I've noticed some weird behavior when going back to the previous page. For example:

1. I'm not logged in and go to `/home`, which is only shown for logged in users. I get redirected to `/login`, which is correct.
2. I click in my browser (top left) to go to the previous page. Note that I don't go to the previous page by clicking on a link on the website.
3. For less than a second, I can see the content of `/home`, then I get redirected back to `/login`, which is handled by `AuthGuard`.

I use a boolean state hook for showing children and noticed that it's still set to `true` for a tiny bit when going back to the previous page. `true` is still the old value it got when loading `/login`. Why doesn't it start afresh?

Here's my `AuthGuard`:

```
const AuthGuard = ({ children, restriction }) => {
  const [canShowChildren, setCanShowChildren] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const { user, loading } = useAuth();
  const router = useRouter();

  // I need to use useEffect & async because some user data can only be retrieved
  // asynchronously, though I haven't included that part here because it's 
  // irrelevant to the problem.
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      if (loading || !router.isReady) return;

      if (restriction === "public") {
        setCanShowChildren(true);
        return;
      }

      if (!user) {
        router.push("/login");
        return;
      }

      ...
    })();
  }, [loading, restriction, router, user]);

  if (loading || !router.isReady) {
    return <Loading />;
  }

  return canShowChildren ? children : <Loading />;

}
```

I set the restriction in a page through `getStaticProps`, like:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  return {
    props: {
      restriction: "public",
    },
  };
}
```

Comment: Try to reset the state of canShowChildren to false when the component unmounts in your useEffect. Try this: return () => {setCanShowChildren(false);};

Comment: I still get the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working by also saving the route in a state hook. However, I see it as a dirty fix and would love to know more about why is this happening in the first place.

```
const AuthGuard = ({ children, restriction }) => {
  const [canShowChildren, setCanShowChildren] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const { user, loading } = useAuth();
  const router = useRouter();
  const [route, setRoute] = useState<string>("");

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      if (router.asPath !== route) setCanShowChildren(false);
      setRoute(router.asPath);
      ...
    })();
  }, [loading, restriction, router, user, pageRoute]);

  
  if (loading || !router.isReady || router.asPath !== route) {
    return <Loading />;
  }
  
  ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

a simple solution can achieve this is by watching the route in useEffect and whenever it changes clear or reset the state

import {useRouter} from 'next/router'

const Page = (props) => {

const [state, setState] = useState(someState)

const pageRoute = useRouter().asPath

useEffect(() => {
setState(resetState) // When the page route changes the state will reset.
}, [pageRoute])

Comment: This didn't fix the issue, but it steered me in the right direction. I'll post my answer with more details. Thanks.

Comment: I was feeling that you'd say that, And I was totally sure that it might not solve the problem, but it will give you insights into the solution, good luck.